# How to permanently change the appearance of a certain cmd window even after changing its path?

Tags: windows, command-line

How can I change the looks of a specific program (a program running in cmd), even after I relocate it?

I have tried the properties section (which will change the appearance of only the current cmd); after I changed its location the formatting was gone!

How can I change it so that it stays even if I put the program on another pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings are stored in the registry. So you have to export the registry key specific to this program's location, then import it on the new pc.

It is stored here: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\<name of program>`

Comment: Thanx! that was a very useful piece of information.
but now arises the problem of path dependency how work around this one?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Not even sure if it actually takes the location in mind. It seems to only look for the title of the command window as far as I can see. Otherwise, create 2 different instances and see how they look in the registry. But in your question you talk about moving it to a different pc. I answered that part.

Comment: ok, thanks I will try on my own to solve this one.
but it do care about the path I made sure of that.

Comment: If so, then it must be somehow stored in the registry. Maybe a parameter or in the key itself.

Comment: no; its the Name of the registry itself. for example if my program were located in d:\example\bin and its Name is xyz.exe then the Name of the registry under console would be D:_example_bin_xyz.exe and if you Change it, then it will really act accordingly @LPChip

Comment: Right. and if you ommit the path, and only use the xyz.exe it should not matter where it is stored. At least thats the case in Windows 7. Don't know if this changed in windows 8, and neither do I know which windows version you are using.

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 and I will try this (omitting the path) out right now and tell you.

Comment: no; sadly it didn't work out. how exactly should I omit the path. I only left the name of the program but it didn't work out.

Comment: Its possible it doesn't work like that in windows 8 anymore. In windows 7 its only the name as it appears in explorer, so xyz.exe. In worst case, you can use a shortcut that points to the right location, and put the location of the shortcut in the registry, which could be on someone's desktop (%USERPROFILE%\Desktop) though I'm not sure if this will work in the registry too. But other than this, I can't help you. If you know where the program is going to be stored, edit the .reg file after export and only then copy it to the other pc and run it.

Comment: yes I was thinking about something like that and will try to implement it. ok, thanks again for your help.